# How to combine good result with google page speed and putting css on bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagespeed

I am trying to get good results for pageSpeed with google on my page.

I got good results but putting CSS and JS on bottom of the page.

But I got the problem: my page renders without CSS, then got rendered normally after css is loaded (it produces like a page flash)

I tried to solve by putting style on body display: none
then added the jquery document.ready and put display to normal, but my google page speed results went down again.

Is there a solution/tip to get good pageSpeed results with good rendering of the page.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the css in the head section. PageSpeed suggestions are just that, suggestions. And the standard  way of loading a web page is the standard. The marginal increases in speed would not be worth the effort you'll put in achieving them.

Comment: If your site loads consistent and your visitor is not waiting on long loading times, I would not bother. It is good to take a concern in it, but you should determine if its worth it.

Comment: Considering your much more experience on that platform, I don't want to be precise but I'm used to imply and tried to load `css` at the end of <head> (instead of rendering twice in your case) and then `javascript` at the end of the <body> section as you do to be able to cause more rapid results as I learned and experienced till now consequently via [pagespeed/insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and many other articles I read.

Comment: zip your all css,js,and html,images files and you can use version your all css files (style.css?v=1.0) one more thing move your js under `<body>` top of the `</body>`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately with HTTP/1 we are forced to bundle all our css rule-sets into one file to prevent multiple resource requests, this won't be the case with HTTP/2.

Speed is definitely something you would want to improve in a website, but the important point here is how fast useable content is in front of the visitors. The resources you use will eventually increase in size,  this shouldn't be proportional to the time the user waits to be able to use the page. **Focus on perceived performance.**

*What is the current problem with CSS files located in the `head` tag?*

A: They block rendering until the file is loaded.

*What can you do about it?*

There is a specification that involves the `preload` keyword used in the `link` tag to load css files asynchronously.

> This specification defines the preload keyword that may be used with
>   link elements. This keyword provides a declarative fetch primitive
>   that initiates an early fetch and separates fetching from resource
>   execution.

*Source: [**w3**](https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/)*

This, however, is still not fully supported by browsers. (Browser support [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#search=preload)).

A solution is to use [**loadCSS**](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) which is basically a polyfill.

> The new `<link rel="preload">` standard enables us to load stylesheets
>   asynchronously, without blocking rendering, and loadCSS provides a
>   JavaScript polyfill for that feature to allow it to work across
>   browsers, as well as providing its own JavaScript method for loading
>   stylesheets.
>
> ---

Finally, the technique that is commonly proposed is the following:

1. Load a stylesheet with the critical css rule-sets to be able to display
   information to the user, such as layout formatting, this is included as you normally would, in the `head` tag with `<link>`.
2. Load the stylesheet with the css rule-sets that are not critical to the initial rendering of the page which will be loaded with loadCSS.

---

*Notes:*

- If you go down this path make sure to check tools like
  [**webpagetest.org**](http://www.webpagetest.org/) to test perceived performance.